# Python - Dictionnary and tuples, retrieving key after sorted()

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, sorting

So for example, I got a dictionary:

```
points_tuples = [(team1_id,team1_points),(team2_id,team2_points),(team3_id,team3_points)]
```

And then I used the sorted() method, to sort by points:

```
sorted_tuple = sorted(periods_tuples,key=lambda team: team[1],reverse=True)
```

I would like to get the team id of the first place team for example...

How can I do that?

Thanks,
Ara

Comment: That's not a dictionary. It's a list of tuples you have there.

Comment: What do you want to happen if there are two teams with the same maximal number of points?

Comment: @DSM, It's a bit complicated how the league works for ties, so I will implement another function to figure that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a dictionary, it's a list of tuples! But you can access the first id using

```
top_score_id = sorted_tuple[0][0]
```

The first zero is for the first tuple in the list, the second means the first value in that tuple.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to sort if you only retrieve the first place team. Use [`max`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max):

```
>>> points_tuples = [
...     ('team1', 10),
...     ('team2', 30),
...     ('team3', 20),
... ]
>>> max(points_tuples, key=lambda team: team[1])
('team2', 30)
>>> max(points_tuples, key=lambda team: team[1])[0]
'team2'
```

Comment: I need to get who finished second also.

Comment: @AraSivaneswaran, Then use `sorted_tuple[0][0]`, `sorted_tuple[1][0]` as others answered.

Answer (score 0):

as sorted_tuple is returning the list sorted by point then you can take the first tuple by `sorted_tuple[0]` .team id will be the 0th element of that tuple as per your touple structure.

```
team_id = sorted_tuple[0][0]
```